# How to specify backgroundcolor with dvisvgm

Tags: dvi, dvisvgm

I am trying to convert a DVI to SVG with some white background. How do I need to specify the color?

I have tried to convert the following example using latex (generating the DVI) and dvisvgm (generating the SVG) but the resulting file has no background.

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\special{dvisvgm:bgcolor white}

\begin{document}
Hello1 \tikz [baseline] \fill [fill=blue!80!black] (0,.75ex) circle[radius=.75ex];
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it should be `\special{bgcolor white}` which is what latex color uses for `\pagecolor{white}` in `dvisvgm.def` but it doesn't work either

Comment: The special should look like this: `\special{background White}`. `bgcolor` is just the name of dvisvgm's handler that processes the background color special as defined in the dvips manual. So it's a bit misleading, I must confess. A list of supported color names can be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips).

Comment: @Martin your comment `\special{background White}` does the trick, I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: Great to hear that it works now. I've added an answer.

Comment: @Martin I guess we should update dvisvgm.def so `\pagecolor{white}` would work, thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. I could also add support for special `bgcolor`. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: First the whole mechanism of how to input the special was also not clear. I found a webpage then mentioning `\special` whcih gave the clue. Before that I had assumed that a special commandline parameter would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dvisvgm currently only supports the `background` special as specified in the [dvips manual](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/dvips.html#Color-specials). The syntax looks like this:

```
\special{background <color specifier>}
```

where the color specifier can be either one of the 68 [dvips color names](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips) or a color model (rgb, cmyk, hsb, gray) followed by the proper number of color parameters representing the color in that model, e.g. `gray 1` or `rgb 1 1 1` for white.
So, in your example, you just have to replace the special with

```
\special{background White}
```

and a corresponding white rectangle will be added (because SVG doesn't support coloring the canvas itself).

Comment: hm, that is not what is what the documentation says ;-(.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What documentation? The one of dvisvgm or dvips? If you refer to `bgcolor` in the dvisvgm man page, it's the name of the special handler which processes the `background` statement. It's not the name of the special itself. That's indeed a bit misleading.

Comment: the dvisvgm man page. And yes it is really much misleading. Why is it in the same list as color and dvisvgm if it is not meant to be used in a special? Or asked the other way round: when would you ever need `bgcolor`?

Comment: The names of the special handlers can be used to disable the processing of groups of specials with option `--no-specials`, e.g. `--no-specials=bgcolor` prevents changing the background color. The `background` statement used to be part of the `color` handler but someone requested a way to disable this special separately, so I moved it to a separate handler (almost 10 years ago, I can't remember all details). Option `--list-specials` prints the names of all handlers that can be disabled individually.

Comment: aha, you could add that to the documentation ;-). It is rather unclear as it is now, I interpreted that as a list of real specials to use in the document.

Comment: Yes, that part of the documentation is pretty old and could certainly be improved. I've just added some more details to it in my local repo. I'll update the manual page together with the next release.